# How To Handle Update On Table From External API

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, queue

Users submit a request which passes to an external API and also a insert in database with a status code "1".
API Process the record and update status code to "2" in my mySQL database.
How can I know the API update the status code from "1" to "2"?

Using Laravel Queue With Redis.
I've tried with working linux CRONJOB but I don't want to use that

Comment: is there any page where api hit to update your table or api update your db by itself?

Comment: update database itself

Comment: Then cronjob is the solution, set it in every 5 min or as per your need and query to your table and set LASTCHECKID in somewhere like in config table and then on next script run check where id >= LASTCHECKID, so you dont need to check whole table everytime.

Answer (score 0):

Try to explore the Laravel Broadcasting

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/broadcasting

When the Update function is successfully run, add the broadcast event then listen to it using javascript in your UI. (Laravel echo)